# Assembly windows functions - numbers after function name?

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to make a program in assembly that uses some Windows API functions, specifically GetConsoleWindow, MessageBox, and ShowWindow. I found how to use MessageBox on a random website, by externing `_MessageBoxA@16`. I tried the same for GetConsoleWindow, with `extern _GetConsoleWindowA@16`, however on linking a get an error: `(.text+0x4): undefined reference to GetConsoleWindowA@16'`.

I'm compiling with the following commands: `nasm -f win32 message.asm -o message.obj`, `ld message.obj -o message.exe` Where do the numbers at the end of the function name come from? (e.g. @16). Or should I be externing something else entirely?

Comment: `GetConsoleWindowA@16` of course not exist anywhere. wrong symbol

Comment: They signal the size of the arguments in bytes. `GetConsoleWindowA` takes no arguments so you can either omit the number or use `@0` (not sure which one).

Comment: Keep the question interesting, and possibly useful to you so you can avoid the same mistake next time.  Tell us how you decided to use _GetConsoleWindowA@16

Comment: Please note that “externing” is not a commonly used word and may confuse people.

Comment: How 'random' was that website?  In other words _tell us what it is!!_  Hence (probably) the downvotes (although I didn't - in fact I voted up).

Answer (score 7):

Those are [decorated names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names), specifically using the C decoration for the `__stdcall` calling convention<sup>1</sup>:

> Leading underscore (_) and a trailing at sign (@) followed by the number of bytes in the parameter list in decimal

The trailing `A` or `W` character designates the ANSI or Unicode version of the API call. For [GetConsoleWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) there is no separate ANSI or Unicode version, as the API doesn't directly (or indirectly) use character strings as either parameters or return value. The decorated symbol is thus `_GetConsoleWindow@0`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Only applies to 32-bit code. In 64-bit code, symbols are exported undecorated, e.g. `GetConsoleWindow` in this case.*